# Difference between router and router-deprecated in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I've updated from "beta.17" to "2.0.0-rc.1" and I don't understand when I should use router and when router-deprecated?

Comment: well, you never **should** use anything `-deprecated` unless you have to (i.e. can't update your code to use the new version)

Comment: Or if your'e going through the official demos/tutorials - they use the router-deprecated

Comment: The rc.1 router has been abandoned now, so at least at the moment it might be wise to use router-deprecated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## UPDATE TO ANGULAR2 RC

There are alot of changes has been made in routing in angular2 after RC some of them points i am going to mention here may help someone :-

1. `angular2/router` has been changed with `@angular/router`
   (also you can use old functionality of routing using import of `@angular/router-deprecated` but as of now we have to use `@angular/router`).
2. `@RouteConfig` has been changed with `@Routes` .

for example :-

```
@Routes([
  {path: '/crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent},
  {path: '/heroes',        component: HeroListComponent}
])
```

Rest ill update soon my answer as per update in changelog.
Thanks to @Benedikt for comment
[Article for new @Route update to angular2 RC](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WLSNV3V1AKdwLwRiLuN7JqbPBKQ_S5quRlcT5LPIldw/edit?pref=2&pli=1#heading=h.blfh5ya9sf5r)

Comment: more accurate: `angular2/router` has been changed to `@angular/router-deprecated` and a new `@angular/router` has been added

Comment: I did not know about @Routes. This will solve my problem

Comment: @drewmoore but how are working now? I don't see name property.

Comment: @illorian, the `name` property is no longer used in the new router.

Comment: @Gnarlywhale so it is really only path and component now. What about RouterLink?

Comment: [This](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WLSNV3V1AKdwLwRiLuN7JqbPBKQ_S5quRlcT5LPIldw/edit#heading=h.blfh5ya9sf5r) is the offical document for the breaking changes for the new angular/router. Even there the name propery is used...

Comment: Hi @PardeepJain, your solution helped me massively, but not entirely. Could you please just tell me what's the import I need? I tried `import { Router, Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from "@angular/router";` but it didn't worked as it "has no exported member 'Routes'. May I ask you for directions?